# Change application default tile in runtime on Windows 10 UWP

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10

I need to change color of application tile to accent color.
On wp8 I used ShellTile class and change icon to transparent, so [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25011753/change-default-tile-image-url) works.

But on Windows 10 ShellTile is missing. There is another possible method using TileUpdateManager, but it's changing icon for LiveTile, not for default Tile Icon.

This code works for updating LiveTile, but not for default icon.

```cs
TileContent content = new TileContent()
{
    Visual = new TileVisual()
    {
        TileMedium = new TileBinding()
        {
            Content = new TileBindingContentAdaptive()
            {
                BackgroundImage = new TileBackgroundImage()
                {
                    Source = new TileImageSource("Assets/Tiles/FlipCycleTileMediumOp.png")
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Update(new TileNotification(content.GetXml()));
```

And this kinda resolve the problem, but when I disable "live tile" option, icon returns to default.

Comment: Can't you just set the tile background color to transparent in the app manifest?

Comment: Can't you run your code on application startup?

Comment: No. This is one of the settings option, so I need to change it via code. And of course there must be option to return icon to default, so it must be done programmaticaly